# Embedding a custom React-Native component library

Tags: react-native

I created a small custom component library of React-Native components called simply: **united-native-components**.  I want to embed that library in my larger React-Native application called **UnitedApp** (yes, I am not very creative in my naming). However, when I go to run the **UnitedApp** React-Native application (npm run ios or npm run android), I am faced with:

```
Loading dependency graph...(node:843) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 
Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-animated
  Paths: 
/Users/boris.badenov/Development/UnitedApp/node_modules/united-native-components/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json collides with 
/Users/boris.badenov/Development/UnitedApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/release/package.json

This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.
... additional stack material printed out
```

It is not consistent, I have had it fail with a collision on the **react-native** package and surprisingly, the **Sample** in the react-native/Libraries

My question is, am I missing some value in the component package.json that allows me to embed it as I would any other NPM package and not have this package collision issue?

This seems a very common approach where you have packages of React-Native components that are embedded in a larger application just as you would frameworks in an iOS application or *.jar files for an Android application.

Comment: It seems you've two package.json files in your project. As far as I know, you can only have one. Delete the package.json inside united-native-components and add its dependencies to your main package.json file instead.

Comment: Hmm, I guess we can have as many as we want. The content might create some problems.

Comment: No, the component library is developed independently and I cannot delete the package.json file.  In addition, all of the other react-native frameworks I use and install through npm have package.json files as part of their download package. So, I don't believe you can only have one package.json file.